# Firefox @font-face with local file - downloadable font: download failed

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I am having an issue with using a font accessed via a relative URL.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
    src:url('../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.eot');
    src:url('../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg'),
        url('../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When I access the web page the font doesn't work and in the console I get this:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "ElegantIcons" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147500037
source: file:///...snipped.../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.woff @ file:///...snipped.../src_poke/fonts-style.css
```

Accessing the file by copying/pasting the URL into the browser address bar shows that it is the correct URL as I can download the font.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A hat tip to Jonathan Kew's response on a [relevant mozilla bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760436):

> I believe this is working as designed. AIUI, the issue here is that
>   for a page loaded from a file:// URI, only files in (or below) the
>   same directory of the filesystem are considered to be "same origin",
>   and so putting the font in a different subtree (../font/) means it
>   will be blocked by security policy restrictions.
>
> You can relax this by setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to
>   false in about:config, but as this gives the page access to your
>   entire local filesystem, it's something to be used with caution.

To summarise, the "fix" without re-arranging your files:

- Open about:config
- Set `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to false
- Beware of the security implications

The best way is, however, to make sure any resources are accessible without going back up the file system first.

**Note:** the origin policy is calculated based on the html, NOT the css file! So a font file right besides an css file might not work, which is very confusing. *(At least this is what I thought was the case with Firefox!)*

**Follow ups:**

eradman comments:

> It's the other way around: relative paths are [relative to the CSS file](http://w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url).

chrylis responds:

> You'd think that, but the actual code in Firefox doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I still get the error. Also, I moved the awesome-font files to the same directory as the css, and I still get the issue. :(

Comment: Perhaps you can post a new question and link it here, so I can see how you are doing things?

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin: a seriously Big Thank You®!!! I was going nuts on this, and this was *exactly* the fix I needed for displaying a page than had been fetched by wget with --page-requisites. You rock!

Comment: @Ciwan note that the origin policy is calculated based on the html, NOT the css file! So a font file right besides an css file might not work, which is very confusing.

Comment: This is still an issue for me. It works fine on chrome :( .

Comment: It's the other way around: relative paths are relative to the CSS file. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url

Comment: @eradman You'd think that, but the actual code in Firefox doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: What's the point in changing your settings in Firefox? You want the visitors of your website to see the right fonts, and can't expect them to change their browser settings first.

Comment: Also, importing the fonts relative to either the css file or the html file both don't work. Not in FF nor Chrome.

Comment: @poepje you don't seem to understand that this is about local HTML/CSS i.e. web development, not a publicly open website.

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin I do, but isn't the idea of a website that it's going to be published on the web eventually? You already have the fonts, so I wouldn't know why *you* would want to use `@font-face` for yourself?

Comment: Still an issue in 2019. This question doesn't rank very well for the question, but it's the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

For local file we have to use `local()`

For external we have to use `url()`

According to the document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

For example

```
src:local('../src_main/fonts/ElegantIcons.eot');
```

Comment: This **only** applies if the local machine is both the server and the client. Once a website is hosted on a server and requested by a different machine as the client, `local()` refers exclusively to the client machine, over which the website cannot expect to have any kind of control. `local()` should only be used in conjunction with `src()`, in order to allow for a locally installed font to take precedence over (or act as a fallback to) a webfont.

Answer (score 4):

@CharlesGoodwin @eradman  Actually, both statements about the origin seem true except that they probably talk about two different things: same-origin check is based on the originating HTML file, while relative URLs for font faces are resolved relative to the CSS file containing the @font-face rule.

Moreover, originating HTML file is not the file that uses the font. I have the following local file structure.

```
<base-directory>/index.htm
<base-directory>/ARPLS/toc.htm
<base-directory>/dcommon/css/fonts.css
<base-directory>/dcommon/fonts/myfont.woff
```

*fonts.css* references *myfont.css* via *url(../fonts/myfont.woff)* and *toc.htm* reference *fonts.css* via *<link ... href="../dcommon/css/fonts.css">*. *index.htm* has a hyperlink to *toc.htm*.
Now, I have bookmarked both *index.htm* and *toc.htm*. If I use the *index.htm* bookmark, the font is rendered correctly. If I use the *toc.htm* bookmark, the font fails to load. I guess this is because *myfont.woff* is in a sub-directory of the directory containing *index.htm* but not of the directory containing *toc.htm*.

Observed in Firefox 38.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the original source css has relative font face declaration like so `../fonts/some-font.woff`, and you compile that source CSS into bundle.css which resides at some other path. So that way you lose the path to font.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into this issue since the latest update (about 1.5 weeks ago). This thread specifically, plus the comments in Bugzilla helped me to understand the problem as a security feature.  The solution that I found (eventually) was to take my Firefox preferences off of "strict" security and set to standard/default.  "Strict" even says it will break some sites, so I think that this goes to the above point that this issue is by-design.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, and should have been put under the recognised answer already provided as all it does is agree with that.