# when we mouse out the input elements, page is not displaying properly in firefox

Tags: css, angularjs, firefox

[image]

I have a css for hovering over the input elements from the external css file which is working perfectly in chrome and IE but not working in firefox.

After hover when we mouse out also it is having the hover value(black).Instead it should have the light ash color.Can anyone help where it is going wrong?

```
.azfs.input-field:hover {
border-color: #414141;
}

.azfs.input-field {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 6px 13px;
margin: 0;
background: #fff;
font-family: AllianzSansWeb,Arial;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.2em;
font-size: 16px;
color: #414141;
border-radius: 0;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
}
```

Note: Updated the firefox with the latest version as well.still same issue.

Comment: Can you post a complete example that demonstrates the issue? A quick and dirty [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebuLekjp/) shows no problem.

Comment: Actually I cannot set up those input elements since all the input elements are custom directives which I cannot make it as standalone. Can you give me some suggestions like how to approach this issue? The problem is it is wrking fine in chrome and IE.

Comment: The problem is I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: on the firefox console I am getting this error "downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "allianz-sans-bold" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3002/oneweb/fonts/alsanbol-webfont.ttf". whether the font has anything to do .?

Comment: I am getting the same kind of error in the console which is coming in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817459/firefox-font-face-with-local-file-downloadable-font-download-failed

Comment: `border-color: #414141 !important;` maybe

Comment: Its not working saneesh.