# Css font-family disabled if JS is disabled - is this normal?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face

I'm adding font style with css using the `@font-face` with 4 different formats relatively

```
@font-face {
font-family: "font_name";
src: url("font_name.eot");
src: local("☺"),
url("font_name.woff") format("woff"),
url("font_name.otf") format("opentype"),
url("font_name.svg#font_name") format("svg");
}
```

And it works just fine, however if I disable JS, the font is gone and in the console it says: "downloadable font: download failed...".

This happens(from the console) for the .woff and .otf and I don't understand why. How is JS related to this sort of css code?

Comment: show the style link

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal, do you mean this(?): `font-family: font_name, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;` I add this to the class I want font to apply

Comment: I mean `<link href="???" />` for the font...!

Comment: I'm applying the font-style to the `p` tag. and to apply it, I use class name, in the class name, I use the above `font-family` css code.

Comment: No it's not normal but if you can't demo it it's hard to help.

Comment: Check font file path like "src: url('../fonts/webfont.eot')". if font file in a particular folder

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if svg fonts can contain JavaScript, and in that case they'd require JavaScript to be enabled (duh...) but definitely not for ttf, otf and woff. Dunno about eot.

Comment: In principle you don't need javaScript for that, what browser are you using?

Comment: Mr Lister, I will check that, thanks. blonfu, I tested it with firefox, but I will try other browsers too, thanks. Sarika, the path is fine, it's working with js enabled just fine. Paulie_D, thanks, I will test it then.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful for you but I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817459/firefox-font-face-with-local-file-downloadable-font-download-failed

Comment: Thanks blonfu, but it didn't help much. I tested the svg file, and it's not it. I also tested it for cross-browser and the result is it was firefox "feature". In IE and chrome it's fine. But yet, I can't understand why is this happens only when I disable javascript in FF, because I don't have anything in JS(tested). Very odd. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @alloohaa I cannot duplicate your problem. With JavaScript off, a .woff file will load just as fine as with JavaScript on. Which version of Firefox and which OS are we talking about? Also, does it happen to all .woff files? And more importantly, can you provide a link to a page where this happens?