# downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome")

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I've been having trouble displaying a font on my website, it works perfectly whenever i open the file locally but fails when i take it live. after checking the console on firefox i ended up with this

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065
```

Found others online with the same issue but no solutions

The GET request is returning a 404 but the font exists in the right folder, any ideas on a fix?

Comment: can you add your code snippet ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19817459/14945696) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try access the font's URL and you may see `Forbidden`.

If so, you should change the permissions to the font's folder (or file) and allow World to Execute, that is e.g. **CHMOD** it to **755** through FTP

Answer (score 0):

This could also be the MIME type in IIS - for me it was failing on a .woff2 file.

(Trying to load the file directly in Chrome on the actual server gave me the most informative error.)

I added .woff2 to the MIME Types in IIS (at the server level) and the file loads now.

[image: screen shot of added .woff2 MIME type]